# CKEditor5 use model in custom Data Processor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I was playing with CKEDitor5, and I tried to create a custom Data Processor. I'd like to use the model in the `toData` conversion, but the method is called with the `view/DocumentFragment` object. So my question is that how could I convert that into a `model/DocumentFragment` object (or how to access the model from a data processor).

**Update** (as it cannot fit into a comment):
Let me try to better explain what exactly I try to do (or I already did so far) in a bit more detail. I figured out how to use access the model itself, but that seemed like a bad solution as you also pointed it out.

So basically I want to create a `DataProcessor` to convert the editor data to BBCode, which sounds reasonable enough I guess.

On one hand, the `toView` method is simple, as the BBCode to HTML conversion can be assumed to be already implemented (in my case). And from HTML it seems to be trivial to load the editor data (by the same process used by the Markdown processor).

On the otherhand, it seems easier to convert to BBCode from the model data rather than the view. Mostly because the `view/DocumentFragment` object and the rest of the view tree is pretty much just another representation of the DOM or HTML. I don't really care for whether bold is `<b>` or `<strong>` i just want to know whether the `text` node has the `bold` attribute or not.

By using the model, I hope to work with the semantics rather than the representation used in HTML. It seems a bit pointless to basically map all HTML tags to their BBCode equvivalents (even if CKE5 does a good job of providing consistent HTML tags). So from my point of view, using the model just makes more sense. Converting from semantic representation to a "data format" is easier than to convert to a "data format" (view tree, DOM, HTML, morse code) and then create a "representation map" after that.

For a long time what blocked us from using RTEs or WYSIWYG editors were exactly the difficulty of converting from HTML to BBCode. Now CKE5 has model, which seems to be easy to convert to anything, as it is independent not just from the HTML format but the HTML displayed in the editor as well (this cannot be said about the view tree as it is exactly the HTML in the editor - at least it is not whatever contenteditable produces, but still not good enough).

*Also*: I just made a `Plugin` that sets the `DataProcessor`, as that was what the Markdown feature kind of does as well (in the docs somewhere). Is that a bad idea?

Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: I see your points. I'd think that BBCode output is exactly the case for the view -> DOM -> desired output conversion. Do note, that the approach you described has its drawbacks when it comes to expanding the editor. The set of elements of DOM or view is pretty stable, so you do your work only once. Model, OTOH, is flexible and any developer might come up with any element that might be converted to a complex structure in the view/DOM. You will have to write model->BBCode conversion for every new plugin you will include.

Comment: Also, do note that converting model is tricky and we have multiple tools for this. For example, texts in the model are "flat", so you'd have to break them into tags on your own. I guess that all I am trying to say is that by converting the model to another format you more-or-less re-do all the work that others already did.

Comment: Lastly, it is fine to use a plugin to set data processor.

Comment: Your points are absolutely valid, and probably I'll have to do some research. However, I think we see different things as the most challenging part of the data conversion. What I want to avoid is to duplicat what CKE5 features do in the `buildViewConverter` part. As I could have a bold plugin which uses `<span class="bold">` if I wanted to. Also complex models still could be serialized in BBCode unlike in HTML as `[modelName attr1="attr1val" ...]text[/modelName]`. DOM would help if my syntax mirors HTML exactly. I feel model is just better fitted for anything else than HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently, a [similar question was raised on CKE5 GitHub](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/620). The question is about getting JSON data as editor output, but topic raised by you is also partially covered.

> (...) how to access the model from a data processor

There are certain problems and risks connected with operating straight on the model. This is not something that is recommended. It is explained in the linked post.

> (...) my question is that how could I convert that into a `model/DocumentFragment`

This is a better (less risky) approach than operating straight on the model. However, I have to ask - why do you want to convert from the model? Maybe there's a better solution to your problem?

To convert between view and model, one would have to use `DataController#toView` and `DataController#toModel`. `DataController` instance is available at `Editor#data`. To use it in a data processor, the data processor would need access to the editor instance.

I'd suggest creating your own editor class, extending one of CKE5 editor classes. Then, in the new editor class constructor, overwrite data processor and also pass editor instance. Something like:

```
class MyEditor extends ClassicEditor {
  constructor() {
    this.data.processor = new MyDataProcessor( this );
  }
}

class MyDataProcessor() {
  constructor( editor ) {
    this._editor = editor;
  }

  toData( viewDocumentFragment ) {
    const modelDocumentFragment = this._editor.data.toModel( viewDocumentFragment );
    // ...
  }

  toView( modelData ) {
    // ...
    this._editor.data.toView( ... );
    // ...
  }
}
```

These are just to show the direction, not working/tested samples.

Still, I'd like to know why you insist on using the model rather than the view to generate editor output.

BTW. If you go on and implement it like this, the whole process will be a bit silly :). First, you will get a model data, then convert it to view (in data processor), then the editor will take view data and convert it back to the model :). So maybe you will be also interested in overwriting `Editor#setData` method so unnecessary conversions won't take place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, updated the question to answer your questions as it couldn't fit into a comment.